# Howto host and activate WinForm-AddIns that run out of process (new AddInProcess())?

Tags: c#, maf

**Fact**

I'm trying to make a host application that manages `AddIns`(legacy WinForm exe's) out of process using MAF (eg. [Add-ins and Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

The `AddIn` activation is done out of process like:

```
addinToken.Activate<PluginHostView>(new AddInProcess(), AddInSecurityLevel.FullTrust);
```

in the host application that keeps track of plugins and shows them in a `TooStripMenu`.
The `ToolStripMenuitem.Click` event in the host application fires the `PlugIn.ShowMainDialog()` - method  that is part of the `AddIn` contract:

```
(sender as PluginToolStripMenuItem).PlugIn.ShowMainDialog();
```

The `AddIn` X project (a WinForm application) implements the contract in a class that contains:

```
public override void ShowMainDialog()
    {
        new Form1().Show();
    }
```

Running the above host application makes the `AddIn` `X Form` and process hang and it is quite difficult to find out what's  wrong :-(

**Question**

Are there any WORKING samples that use `new AddInProcess()` to host `AddIns` containing `WinForms` out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing Modeless forms out of process in MAF is not very straightforward. The easiest way I have found is to spawn a new thread and do a `ShowDialog` on that thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(()=>
{
    var f = new Form1();
    f.ShowDialog();
});
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```